# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{2^n}$ has a closed form when $0<x<1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

It seems that this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{2^n}$ always converges when $0<x<1$ is real. Does it have a closed form? Not sure if it's relevant, but $nx^n$ from $1$ to $\infty$ has the closed form $x/(x-1)^2$ when $0<x<1.$

Comment: Your $x/(x-1)^2$ result was related to the derivative of a geometric series.  There is nothing equivalent for this question

Comment: Do you have any indication as to why this should converge to a closed form? (I assume by closed form you mean expresseble as a finite combination of radicals). I think otherwise it's unlikely as most of the real numbers are not even computable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [lacunary series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function), so it can't have a closed form using only meromorphic functions.